# How should i set checkbox value to false on single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, double-click

On my edit operation, my check-boxes gets filled according to values stored in database. 
I am using same form for edit and add operations. Now when I click on edit and unchecked the checkbox, it does not return false on single click, it returns false when i double click (for ex uncheck(returns true) -> check(returns true) -> uncheck(returns false)).
 I want checkbox to return false on single click when unchecked, if it is brings checked value.

controller.js

```
$scope.edit = function (user) {
  if (user.Form1007 == "True") {
    $('#Form1007').attr('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('#Form1007').attr('checked', false);
  }
};
```

form.html

```html
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Form 1007 :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="Form1007" value="false" /> 
    <input ng-model="form.Form1007" name="Form1007" type="checkbox"id="Form1007" value="True" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have u tried `user.Form1007 === "true"` ? i.e make triple equals with 't' small

Comment: i don't see why you should overwrite the normal behaviour for checkboxes. just remove the js and you will see that the checkbox will trigger between checked and unchecked accordingly

Comment: I'm trying to understand why are you using hidden input for this?

Comment: Try debugging ur js code using console.log and see what conditions does it enter on single and double clicks

Comment: @JitendraAhuja let me try that

Comment: @dganenco im using hidden for taking false value while adding(inserting)

Comment: @JitendraAhuja I can't take 't' because user.Form1007 has value = "True" . This is the value in the row which I want to edit. So I am checking it inside the if condition and based on that my edit form is filling checkboxes.

Comment: I got the solution for my question, what I did is :-
changed
```
 if (user.Form1007 == "True")
```
to
```
 if (user.Form1007 == true)
```
and instead if taking hidden value and value="True" in input , I changed them as follows
```
ng-true-value = " 'True' " ng-false-value = " 'False' "
```